# Calling Function within other Function with Mobx

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

Working with a simple Mobx Store in React Native, and trying to figure out why I can't get this to work. I have a function that I want to call another function to inatlize a database listener

its pretty simple

```
class Store {
 @action FirstFunction(){
  this.SecondFunction();
   // I also tried:
    SecondFunction();
   //neither worked
 }

 @action SecondFunction(){
   console.log("Second Function!");
 }

}
```

Any ideas? is this possible in mobx? 
can't figure out why it wouldn't be..

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` works, but you have to make sure that the value of `this` is the value you expect it to be.

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/piloxohili/1/edit?js,console))**

```
class Store {
 @action firstFunction() {
   console.log("First Function!")
   this.secondFunction();
 }

 @action secondFunction(){
   console.log("Second Function!");
 }
}

const store = new Store();

console.log("This works:");
store.firstFunction();

console.log("This will throw an error:");
setTimeout(store.firstFunction, 1000);
```